# Swift3: Combining two uint64 type options

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

What's the proper way to write this in Swift 3?

```
let ld = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address | NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber)
```

This is what I get:

> Binary operator | cannot be applied to two NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType operands.

I know they're both `UInt64`'s, but I have no idea how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
do {
    let ld = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address.rawValue | NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue )
}
catch {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw value of these constants as the type `CheckingType` is not an int variant:

```
NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address.rawValue | NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

address in NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address is a enum case, not UInt64. The raw value is UInt64, so you can use raw value like this,

```
do{

let ld = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address.rawValue | NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber.rawValue)

}catch{
    print("error")
}
```

Comment: Further more , it can throw error .. better use try catch block
I have edited the answer with try catch block

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally go with a functional approach, by using an array of `CheckingType` values. This will reduce the code duplication and makes it easy to add new check types to the scanner:

```
let detectorTypes = [
    NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address,
    NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.phoneNumber
].reduce(0) { $0 | $1.rawValue }
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: detectorTypes)
```

Or, to further reduce the duplications in the values prefixes:

```
let types: [NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType] = [.address, .phoneNumber]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.reduce(0) { $0 | $1.rawValue })
```